# View doesn't get updated by Model

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I apologize for this lengthy question but I hope you can stick with me. I have tried to do my best to include all the relevant code snippets in order to explain exactly what I want to achieve.

I am trying to convert my mobile application to the MVVM design pattern and I am experiencing a little difficulty with updating my View from the changes happening in my Model.

I have split my application into a classic Model, View, View Model structure.

Currently, I am trying to propagate data from my Model `SoundScapeData.cs` to my View `HomePage.xaml`.

My `HomePage.xaml` code-behind file looks like this:

```
namespace AX2018
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new HomePageViewModel();
        }

        private void OnConnectButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
            bluetooth.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I bind my data using the `BindingContext` keyword and bind it to a new instance of the `HomePageViewModel` class.

I am connecting to a Bluetooth device, therefore the call to `bluetooth.Connect()` which invokes upon hitting a `Button` in the `HomePage.xaml` View. This Bluetooth device then updates the app with certain values.

I want to emphasize that the Bluetooth connection is working well, and have been verified to work with the View *prior* to converting to the MVVM design pattern.

My ViewModel, `HomePageViewModel.cs`, looks like this:

```
namespace AX2018
{
    public class HomePageViewModel
    {
        private SoundScapeData _soundScapeData;

        public SoundScapeData SoundScapedata { get { return _soundScapeData; } }

        public HomePageViewModel()
        {
            _soundScapeData = new SoundScapeData();
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, I am a little confused how to design the View Model, since the Model `SoundScapeData.cs` currently is so simple as is. Is this intermediary View Model even necessary?

This is my `SoundScapeData.cs` Model:

```
namespace AX2018
{
    public class SoundScapeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _spl;

        public double SPL
        {
            get { return _spl; }
            set
            {
                _spl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the Model, it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and has the relevant function to handle the event in the method `OnPropertyChanged()`.

My View, `HomePage.xaml`, is rather lengthy - it consists of a 9 x 3 grid, with labels placed in certain positions. These labels should reflect values in the `SoundScapeData.cs` Model (and other models, but that is down the road). Here are the relevant snippets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AX2018"
         x:Class="AX2018.HomePage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:HomePageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

...

<Label Text="{Binding SoundScapedata.SPL}" 
FontSize="68" Style="{StaticResource ColoredLabel}" 
Grid.Row="4" 
Grid.Column="1" 
Margin="-20"></Label>
```

As you can see, I have bound the data in the View `HomePage.xaml` to the View Model `HomePageViewModel.cs`, which holds an instance of the `SoundScapeData.cs` Model, which in turn implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

To my understanding, this is the proper approach in terms of data binding when using the MVVM design pattern. However, the changes in SPL are not reflected in my View `HomePage.xaml`.

I update the SPL value in a separate class, `Bluetooth.cs`, which inherits from the `SoundScapeData.cs` Model. Here's a snippet from the `Connect()` method from the `Bluetooth` class:

```
namespace AX2018
{
    public async void Connect()
    {
        public class Bluetooth : SoundScapeData
        ...
        var dbValue = (double)BitConverter.ToUInt16(temp1, 0) / 256 * 48;
        SPL = dbValue;
        ...
    }
}
```

Again, I apologize for this rather long question, but I hope someone out there can point out to me what I am doing wrong. I want to reiterate that the SPL value did update in the View *prior* to converting to MVVM, so I am definitely doing something wrong with my data binding.

Thank you in advance,

kdhansen

Comment: Nicely put together.

Comment: Just saying. In MVVM, the VM adapts the model to the view so the class which should implement INotifyPropertyChanged should be the VM not the model. The model "simulates" a real life object and the VM adapt it to the view. You could have a model Dog which would have legs, size and name, for instance ,and your VM should have as many properties as you need to show (legs,size...) or to control (enabled combobox, visibility flags etc.) in your view. So if you could change your Dog's leg according to a specific value of size it should be the VM the one to control it. Hope I explained myself.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez I see your point. And if I understand you correctly, setting my `HomePage.xaml`'s `BindingContext` to an instance of my Model `SoundScapeData.cs` will properly reflect the changes in my `HomePage.xaml` View. I just did that, but the Label binding the `SoundScapeData.SPL` is still not being updated.

Comment: Im just answering you, but it’s kinda long give me a few mins

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez Alright, thank you.

Comment: Here it is @kdhansen... By the way I was wrong saying Model shouldn't have INotifyPropertyChanged, dont know what I was thinking about so forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer here because comments are too short to explain. If I mispell some names excuse me :P
Let's summarize your scenario:

- HomePage is your View
- HomePageViewModel is your VM
- SoundScapeData is your Model

Now:

**HomePage (view)**

I dont really know if in Xamarin oyu have to duplicate this, remember you set it in your code behind.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
<local:HomePageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

You should change this too:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Spl}" <!--You dont need SoundScapeData anymore this is the public VM property -->
FontSize="68" Style="{StaticResource ColoredLabel}" 
Grid.Row="4" 
Grid.Column="1" 
Margin="-20"></Label>
```

**HomePageViewModel**

It should have as many properties as you need. Let's say your model has just one property *SPL* . Thats your model now you have to put it into the View via your VM. So your VM should have a property (public/private) to adapt it to the View plus your Model.

```
private string spl;
public string Spl
       {
         get {return this.spl;}
         set
            {
            if (this.spl != value)
            {
            this.spl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SPL);
            }
```

When you click the button and you connect to the bluetooth or whatever it does (;P) as it changes the model you have to change your VM properties. Remember, your model has to be the same instance you have in your VM.

So... you should attach to the Model property changed so you change your VM properties and the best way to do that is creating a class (let's try to apply SOLID as much as we can)

```
public class YourNewDataSource
{
    #region Attributes

    private readonly HomePageViewModel homePageViewModel;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods


    public YourNewDataSource(HomePageViewModel homePageViewModel)
    {
      this.homePageViewModel = homePageViewModel;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.homePageViewModel.SoundScapeData.PropertyChanged += this.OnHomePageModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    private void OnHomePageModelPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SPL":
                this.homePageViewModel.Spl = this.homePageViewModel.SoundScapeData.Spl;
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now when you start your application or you want to show your View you have to create a new YourNewDataSource with your VM:

```
public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HomePageViewModel homePageViewModel = new HomePageViewModel();
        YourNewDataSource yourNewDataSource = new YourNewDataSource(homePageViewModel)
        BindingContext = homePageViewModel;
    }
```

Take a look, try it and ask if you don't get some s*** I just wrote here :D

---

I have just took a look to your bluetooth.Connect .

I don't know if it is mandatory for the Bluetooth class to inherit from SoundScapeData but right now it won't work cause you lose the VM's model when you connect. If you don't really need to inherit from SoundScapeData just add a parameter to your connect method and pass the Vm.SoundScapeData to it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Juan. I'm molding over your answer right now but am slightly confused as to why you have left out the implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the VM. This approach does not seem to follow the approach I have seen utilized in other cases, e.g. in MS Docs' [Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/gg405484(v%3dpandp.40)#creating-the-view-model-using-xaml). However, I'll keep your answer in mind while trying to fix my issue.

Comment: You need to implement it. If you don’t do that the view will never know when the VM changes. If you use the VM like you are doing you have just created a class which has another class (model) and using it as datacontext. You model os directly bound to the view right now just using a class you called XXXXVM but it doesnt really work as a VM

Comment: @kdhansen take a look to this : http://www.learnmvvm.com/theory.html#top

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looks like a good resource for learning MVVM. 

I got it to work now but the structure is not quite what I intended.

I moved my `Bluetooth` class into my `HomePageViewModel` and also moved all of the properties from the `SoundScapeData` class into the VM. I added a `BaseViewModel`, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which my other VM's will inherit from.

So the VM now updates very well. But this is definitely an intermediary work-around since the `Bluetooth` class should be a service, which the other VM's should be able to utilize.

Comment: Glad it helped :D My answer is what a basic MVVM should look like, you can improve applying SOLID etc. Your Bluetooth class was fine being a single class you just need to pass the right parameters so it keeps their instance. If my answer helped you please upvote it and check it as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are changing the instance of the model and lose the binding of the view.
The response of Juan Carlos is correct, you are not applying pure MVVM, the view should not know the model, the viewmodel is responsible for adapting the model to the view.
The OnConnectButtonClicked that you have in the code behind of the view does not apply the MVVM pattern either, you should use Commands. The link http://www.learnmvvm.com/ is a good starting point.

If you upload an example project of your code to some repository, I'll modify it by applying MVVM and SOLID principles.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Javi. I'm gonna check out learn MVVM and dig a little deeper.